# How to put or post a date value with the symfony date type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So, this is a strange issue I have and I suspect it's due to something obvious I'm missing. Nevertheless, it's taking a lot of my time to solve it so hopefully, someone can give me some insights here.

We are working on a form in Symfony (3.4) and it has a DateType. We can't figure out how to post the value.

If I set the DateType to `['input'] => 'array'`

And do this:

```
PUT http://dev.something.com:8000/app_dev.php/api/v1/section/account/id/1293?
form[dateOfbirth][date][year]=1980&
form[dateOfbirth][date][month]=10&
form[dateOfbirth][date][day]=10
```

It results in:

> "This value is not valid."

After this, I rendered the form in twig, to see what it would post, and I notice the Time is also rendered. So I try:

```
PUT http://dev.something.com:8000/app_dev.php/api/v1/section/account/id/1293?
form[dateOfbirth][date][year]=1980&
form[dateOfbirth][date][month]=10&
form[dateOfbirth][date][day]=10&
form[dateOfBirth][time][hour]=10&
form[dateOfBirth][time][minute]=10
```

But... same problem: It results in:

> "This value is not valid."

So my question is simple: How does one post a date for the DateType field?

Comment: Have you tried without `date` key? Like `form[dateOfbirth][year]=1980`...

Comment: Yes, with that it says: "This form should not contain extra fields."

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of searching, we found the BirthdayType. And this works as expected. It still doesn't explain the problems we had with the DateType, but we can go on now.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html